# Search a folder for keyword with FINDSTR

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to find a string in a folder, but it seems the FINDSTR command line is not working.

I'm wondering if it could be a change in Windows (I'm using Win10), or if I don't have a have the correct "Reference" selected (I do have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime selected).

```vb
Sub ListFilesContainingString()

    Dim myfile As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    
    wrd = InputBox("Word:", "Insert search word")
    If wrd = "" Then
        MsgBox "???"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    myfile = FindFiles(GetFolder, wrd)
    
    If (myfile <> "") Then MsgBox file

End Sub

Function FindFiles(ByVal path As String, ByVal target As String) As String

    ' Run The Shell Command And Get Output
    Dim files As String
    
    files = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("FINDSTR /M """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.*""").StdOut.ReadAll
    
    FindFiles = ""
    If (files <> "") Then
        Dim idx As Integer
        idx = InStr(files, vbCrLf)
        FindFiles = Left(files, idx - 1)
    End If
```

I fixed the typo but FINDSTR is still not working correctly.  My current code is below.  Note that there are several instances of FINDSTR and FIND so I can see what is being returned (the "If, Then x=x" code is only to place a breakpoint).  FINDSTR returns "", FIND returns a file but it isn't a correct file.
FINDSTR does work using a dos/powershell window.

```vb
Sub ListFilesContainingString()

'this macro finds vendor information on the chosen file for each part in the origin file
Dim myfile As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim wrd As String

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolders As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim DirFolderRename As String
    Dim arrFolders() As String
    Dim FolderCount As Long
    Dim FolderIndex As Long
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolders = objFSO.GetFolder(sItem).SubFolders

    FolderCount = objFolders.Count

    If FolderCount > 0 Then
        ReDim arrFolders(1 To FolderCount)
        FolderIndex = 0
        
        For Each objFolder In objFolders
            FolderIndex = FolderIndex + 1
            arrFolders(FolderIndex) = objFolder.Name
        Next objFolder

    Else
        MsgBox "No folders found!", vbExclamation
        
    End If

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFolders = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set wrdAddr = Application.InputBox("Select First Word to Search For", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    wrdCol = wrdAddr.Column
    wrdRow = wrdAddr.Row
    StartCell = Cells(wrdRow, wrdCol).Address
    Range(StartCell).Activate
    wrd = ActiveCell.Value
    While (wrd <> "")
        'wrd = InputBox("Word:", "Insert search word")
        If wrd = "" Then
            MsgBox "???"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        For i = 1 To FolderCount
            TheFolder = GetFolder & "\" & arrFolders(i)
            myfile = FindFiles(TheFolder, wrd)
            If (myfile <> "") Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value & arrFolders(i) & ","
            End If
        Next i
            
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        wrd = ActiveCell.Value
    Wend

End Sub

Function FindFiles(ByVal path As String, ByVal target As String) As String
' Run The Shell Command And Get Output
    Dim files1, files2, files3, files4 As String
    Dim lines
    '''' This works in the dos window
    '  findstr /M /S /I L298P C:\Users\Wm" "Boyd\Documents\Boyd" "Manufacturing\Customers\Inactive\*.xls?
    ''''
    exec ("FINDSTR /M L298P C:\Users\Wm""Boyd\Documents\Boyd""Manufacturing\Customers\Inactive\*.xls?")
    
    files1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("FINDSTR /M """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.xls?""").StdOut.Read
    files2 = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("FINDSTR /M L298P C:\Users\Wm""Boyd\Documents\Boyd""Manufacturing\Customers\Inactive\*.xlsx").StdOut.ReadAll
    If files1 <> "" Then
        x = x
    End If
    files3 = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("FIND """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.xls?""").StdOut.ReadAll
    files4 = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").exec("FIND """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.*""").StdOut.ReadAll
    lines = Split(files1, vbCrLf)
    
    Dim curFile As String
    Dim line
    For Each line In lines
        If (Left(line, 11) = "---------- ") Then
            curFile = Mid(line, 12)
        End If

        If (curFile <> "") Then
            FindFiles = curFile
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    'files = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Exec("FINDSTR """ & target & """ """ & path & "\*.*""").StdOut.ReadAll
    
    'If (files <> "") Then
        'Dim idx As Integer
        'idx = InStr(files, vbCrLf)
        'FindFiles = Left(files, idx - 1)
    'End If
    
    FindFiles = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Would benefit from adding `Option Explicit` to your module and compiling...

Comment: You do this `myfile = FindFiles(GetFolder, wrd)` but then you test for `If (file <> "")`

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. So you will never again run into variable naming issues like this.

Comment: I fixed the type - sorry to bother with that!  But this still does not work.  If I try the example (under the "Search a folder for keyword" thread), FIND does return a value but FINDSTR returns nothing.

Comment: Do you want to search sub folders individually rather than with /S ? Is it just the files1  command you want to run or all 4 of them ? Also I don't understand how you can have a " in the folder name for `C:\Users\Wm""Boy...`

Comment: I was trying a combination of switches to see if the FINDSTR command would return the correct information.  The folder name is \Wm Boyd\....  The only way the command can handle the spaces is by explicitly designating them with the " ".  Note that I also tried running the command in a path that did not contain spaces with the same results.

Comment: @wboyd Why are you using `objFSO.GetFolder(sItem).SubFolders` and then running FINDSTR on each sub-folder when /S will do that ? So the files2,files3,files4 are just tests and the command you want to work is files1. Also what is the `exec("FINDSTR /M L298P...")` line doing.  I have some working code but I want to be sure it is what you want

Comment: I'm at the point that I am just trying to get FINDSTR to return anything, which it doesn't.  The exec("FINDSTR....  was an attempt to see if the exec would run without the shell.  And, of course, it does nothing.

Comment: Well, I just found a problem with the windows 10 pro folder search which may be related.  With the same string in a .xlsx file and a .xls file the search only returns the .xls file.  Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Yes that's what I have found, I guess it's because .xlsx is a compressed folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a log file to record the command executed and the response. This is a first step, if it works the next step would be to parse the response for the information you want.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ListFilesContainingString()

    Const qq = """"
    
    ' get first word from sheet
    Dim wrdCell As Range
    Set wrdCell = Application.InputBox("Select First Word to Search For", _
                 "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    
    If Len(wrdCell.Value2) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No word selected", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' start logging
    Dim Folder As String, FSO As Object, tsLog As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim logfile As String, cmd As String, n As Long
    Dim msg As String, W As Object, s As String
           
    logfile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Log_" _
              & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".txt"
    Set tsLog = FSO.CreateTextFile(logfile)
    Set W = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    ' get folders
    Folder = GetFolder("C:\") 'start in c:\
    If Len(Folder) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' scan for each words
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wrdCell)
         
         ' message box
         msg = msg & vbLf & wrdCell.Address & " " & wrdCell
         
         ' build command
         s = qq & wrdCell & qq & " " & qq & Folder
         cmd = "FINDSTR /M /S " & s & "\*.*" & qq
         tsLog.writeLine "Command" & vbCrLf & cmd & vbCrLf
         
         ' execute
         s = W.exec(cmd).StdOut.ReadAll
         tsLog.writeLine "Result" & vbCrLf & ">" & s & "<" & vbLf
         
         ' next
         n = n + 1
         Set wrdCell = wrdCell.Offset(1)
    Loop
    
    tsLog.Close
    MsgBox "Words searched for " & msg, vbInformation, "See " & logfile
    
    Shell "notepad.exe " & logfile
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath) As String

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then
             MsgBox "Cancelled", vbExclamation
             Exit Function
        End If
        GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
End Function
```