# Search a folder for keyword - FINDSTR Still does not work

Tags: excel, vba, windows, findstr

I can not get FINDSTR to work properly.  Maybe I am not using it correctly (See thread "Search a folder for keyword - FINDSTR not working, that shows the code I am using).

I am trying to emulate the "Search" function in a windows folder.  For instance, I can put a string in the windows folder search window and it will return (show) all the files which contain this string.
I want to create an Excel VBA module that does this, where I read a string from a cell in an excel workbook and use that string to search for any file in a folder containing that string.

If I open a PowerShell window the FINDSTR command DOES work.  I can NOT get it to work in an excel macro.  Help please!

Comment: Please create a [reprex], including all relevant code in your question.

Comment: Please don't open duplicate questions. Repeating [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70072954/search-a-folder-for-keyword-findstr-not-working) with less information is not likely to improve your chances at an answer.

Comment: I tried to ask a question under the previous thread with no response.  I'm new to the forum so maybe I am not asking correctly.

Comment: You can edit your previous question. That will bump it back to the top. What would improve it? Add some more error handling. Does CreateObject succeed? Does exec? Does exec work for some other executable? Are there error messages somewhere?

Comment: Should I continue on this thread or the other?

Comment: Preferably the other one with the code in it.